# Prevent user Selection from Telerik RedComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-combobox

I have included Telerik RedComboBox in my aspx page. I would like to show the list of items in the RedComboBox but user should not allowed to select an item.

Always it should show default value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling the Combobox , you can use enabled and disabled property.

for selecting default value you can use following :

```
RadComboBoxItem item = ddl.FindItemByText(text of your default item here);
item.Selected = true
```